# Tosfos Yom Tov's elegy

Tags: sources-mekorot, song-poetry, tisha-bav

Tosafos Yom Tov is said to have authored elegy, kinnos, to be recited on Tisha B'Av to commemorate the massacres know as Tach V'Tat.

Apparently it has not been included in the standard corpus of kinnos.

Is there an online version?

Answer (score 3):

The elegy is entitled *eleh ezkerah bidma'ot shalish*.

It appears in an edition of *selichot* to be recited on 20 Sivan, available [here](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&restore=1&t=1596188437184&pagenum=10&book=147328) on Otzar HaChochmah (no subscription necessary to access it). However, the print quality of the edition available online is not great.

Comment: There are no 20 Sivan slichot collections on Hebrewbooks? אתמהה

Comment: @DoubleAA Like the selichos for other public fast days, they're often included in the siddur. [Here](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=57996#p=531)'s an example from Siddur Otzar Hatefillos.

Comment: @Meir Although this piyut does not seem to appear in the collection to which you have linked

Comment: @JoelK True. I've seen a source that some kehillos included it in their selichos for one of the tefillos of Yom Kippur, though I haven't found it there either.

Comment: @Meir That custom is mentioned at the end of the introduction to the edition of selichot I linked to. It says they would say it after the Asarah Harugei Malchut at musaf of Yom Kippur

Answer (score 3):

סליחות לכ׳ סיון

אלקינו ואלקי אבותינו

אלקים באזנינו שמענו אבותינו ספרו לנו
פועל פעלת בימי קדם למעננו
בכל דור ודור נוראות, שמת עבורנו
רבות עשית אתה ה׳ נפלאותיך ומחשבותיך אלינו.

גאלתנו בחוזק יד מנחש וצרים
מארי ודוב ונמר ושאר צוררים
דכאונו כמה רגלי חזירי יערים
כמעט נטיו רגלינו ושופכו אשורים.

הלוא אתה אלוקינו זנחתנו לשכחה
יותר מאלף (חמש מאות ושמונים ואחת) שנה ביגון ואנחה
ותזנח משלום נפשינו בפרץ וצווחה
כי עליך הורגנו כל היום נחשבנו כצאן טבחה.

זמן אחר זמן נפשינו חכתה
וארך הקץ וארוכה לא עלתה
חשבון ׳רנ״ו ליעקב׳ חכינו ישע בעתה
קוה לשלום ואין טוב לעת מרפא והנה בעתה.

טוב קוינו והנה אופל ואשמנים
במחזור רנ״ו אחת עשרה שנים
יחדיו נועצו לאחור ולא לפנים
להכחידנו ולמחות את שמינו כעבים וכעננים.

בחרות אפם בנו חיים בלעונו
טף ונשים כצאן לטבחה התקינו
להכרית עולל מחוץ בחורים מרחובותינו
פני כוהנים לא נשאו וזקנים לא חננו.

מלך עליון עד אנה עדי יתמלאון
נוהמים כלבאים וכמות ים ישאון
סגיא כח רמה ידך יחזיון ויראון
עדי כמהי ישעך מופתיך יתפלאון.

הרג רב ויום טבוח בתתנ״ו נגזרה גזירה
ונהרגו קהילות הקודש בזעם ועברה וצרה
זקן ובחור ובתולה ערומים נמשכו לקבורה
חפורות מלאים ילדים ולידות ותלמידי התורה.

טרם היה אזרחי בזרוז יחידו לעקרה
ישמיעוהו מן השמים אל תשלח ידך להשמידה
כמה עתה נשחטים בנים ובנות ביהודה
לא חש להושיע טבוחים ושרופים על מוקדה.

מתן שעשועים ספרי תורות ידועים
נטועים לאוהל פרועים עלי מוטות רקועים
סוף עשאום למנעל רגלי מצורעים
על אלה אני בוכיה ועיני כמים נובעים.

ספר התורה נתעוללה ביד צרים
וגם שכלו דורשיך מפנינים יקרים
עלבונך תבעי ועלבון נפש אדירים
כבתולה חגורת שק על בעל נעורים.

פולין ארץ מלוכה מאז ישבנו בה במנוחת שאננים
עד רבת המהומה נהיתה בתוכה בכמה אופנים
צרות רבות סבבונו במאדינו גלוים ומטמונים
ובנפשינו עד אין מספר להרוגים הגדולים עם הקטנים.

קמו יוונים נקבצו עלינו להשחיתנו והרחיבו כמה חורבנות
בתי כנסיות ובתי מדרשות עם קהילות הקודש נחרבו בעוונות
קדריים גם המה עזרו להרע רעות זו מזו שונות
וישבו ממנו שביה עניה לארץ נכריה באין רחמנות.

רעות הספורות כמוקדמות לא חסרו מהר דבר
הנהרגים נשטחו בארץ על פניה והחיים לתוכה השליכו להיקבר
רעשה הארץ ותהום כל קריה כי האויב גבר
פני זקנים לא נהדרו צוארם לטבח פשטו גאון עם חבר.

שנת ח״ת ושנת ט״ת הרבה מאוד לקינו בהם נחנו זרע אובהיך
אשר קיוינו שבשנת זא״ת ישוב איש אל אחוזתו מארץ שביך
תשלם לנו השנים אשר אכל המשחית עד למרבה המולק החסין הגוזם והטיב לנו בטובך
כהבטחת ׳ונתן לך רחמים ורחמך והרבך׳.

תוספות יהיה על העיקר בכפל רחמים ומרובה
יו״ם מחר כי תבוא על שכרי בזה ובבא
טו״ב ומטיב אתה לטובים אחד הממעיט ואחד המרבה
ה׳נני ל׳שמך ו׳לזכרך י׳חלנו נפש לעבדך ביראה ובאהבה רבה.

הנקר״א בהיותו קרוב ונמצא כי נדרשהו ונבקשנו
ל׳שולחי י׳דבר פ׳י ה׳ סלכחתי ולי ׳כדבריך׳ ישיב ויעננו
מ׳שיח וקל-יה השליח זה יגאלנו וזה יקדים לבוא ולבשרנו
נ׳ורא מרום וקדוש חי וקים ה׳ הוא אלוקינו.

ה׳יום אם בקולו נשמע נזכה ל׳אחישנה׳
ע׳דן עדנים פתרונים כלם כולו, הלא ב׳עתה׳ לא יאחרנה
ל׳ביה לפומיה לא גלה למתי יקימנה
ר׳וח אפינו משיח ה׳ על ידו התשועה ועינינו תראנה:

Comment: Sorry for the format above (don't know how to right justify the Hebrew here).  This is my first post on the site. It just so happens I had my daughter type in the text of this kinnah two days ago so I could use as part of a Sefaria source sheet (on Tosafot Yom Tov and Tach v'Tat).

Comment: Hi Raanan, welcome and thank you. Are you sure this is the correct kinah? The other answer indicates it is called אלה אזכרה בדמעות שליש

Comment: @DoubleAA He signed his name in it: תוספות יהיה על העיקר בכפל רחמים ומרובה יו״ם מחר כי תבוא על שכרי בזה ובבא טו״ב ... ה׳נני ל׳שמך ו׳לזכרך י׳חלנו

Comment: Looks like he wrote more than one. This one also appears in the collection I linked to in my answer, starting on page 3.

Comment: He signs name by putting Tosfos and Yom and Tov, and then an acrostic that spells Halevi Heller.  I had those letters underlined in my source sheet but did not copy over to this site.

Comment: I do see the Eila Ezkera as well in the “Lichvod Yom Tov” book by Maimon, Rav Kook press, c. 1957